# How do you make leaflet popup window full screen on small screens?

Tags: css-position

On smaller screens (phones) the leaflet popup window has a tendency to overflow the screen.  I'd like to write some css rules fenced inside a min-width and max-width media query to make the popup window go full screen for small devices only.

There is a ton of positioning done by the library, and I'm having a hard time over-riding those rules.

```
@media (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 500px) {
    .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
    }
    .leaflet-popup-content {
        position: fixed; //Tried absolute, too
        top: 0;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
    }
}
```

[Example JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3gyhwek/2/)